# Checking holomorphic domain

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $z=x+iy$ and $f(z) = 3 x y^2 + i y^3$ let $\frac{\partial}{\overline{\partial z}} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$

Computing the Cauchy–Riemann equations of $f$ leads to $\frac{\partial}{\overline{\partial z}}f(z)=3ixy =0 \iff x=0 \text{ or }y=0$

Can we conclude that $f$ is holomorphic on the real and the imaginary line ?

I'm new to complex analysis I thought the domain where a function is holomorphic must be an open set.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. And therefore there is no non-empty open set $\subset\Bbb C$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is holomorphic.

Comment: In fact when can we infer that the set where a function is holomorphic is an open set ?

Comment: It depends upon the definition of holomorphic function that you are using. Since you wrote “I thought the domain where a function is holomorphic must be an open set”, I assumed that, under the definition that you are working with, the answer would be affirmative.